# RDAVIDWebService (R package) manual installation, or alternative tool

Tags: r, bioconductor, gene-ontology

Recently, I had to re-install all my R packages (R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18) -- "Camp Pontanezen") and it turns out that `"RDAVIDWebService"` is not available anymore on Bioconductor:

> `package ‘RDAVIDWebService’ is not available for Bioconductor version '3.13'`

Is there an another way to install it (couldn't find the files on the Bioconductor site to install the package manually) or is there another R package that allows to use the [DAVID tool](https://david.ncifcrf.gov/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That package was deprecated in Bioconductor version 3.13 after several attempts to contact the package author/maintainer.

Your options include reverting back to Bioconductor version 3.12 or using one of the other options for GO/pathway enrichment analyses, e.g. [topGO](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/topGO.html), [enrichR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/enrichR/index.html), or [clusterProfiler](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/clusterProfiler.html).